# Changing elements of an array to user input with pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to ask the user for 3 different strings, if the second string is a part of the first string it will replace that part with the third string. In addition to this, I must use pointer arithmetic to index through any arrays/strings. For example:

```
string1 = foobar  
string2 = oba  
string3 = 12345   
output = fo12345r
```

My program works when the pattern string (string2) and the replacement string (string3) are the same lengths, but if not I get weird results.

For example:

```
s1: foobar  
s2: obar  
s3: 3333  
r: fo3333
```

(^works)

```
s1: foobar  
s2: obar  
s3: 33  
r: fo33  ends without including the original last 2 characters ('a','r')
```

(^doesn't work)

```
s1: foobar  
s2: obar  
s3: 12345  
r: fo1234  ends without including the last new character ('5')
```

(^doesn't work)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void GetString(char *str);
void StringReplace(char *original, char *pattern, char *replacement);

int main(void){
    char originalstring[256];
    char patternstring[32];
    char replacement[32];

    printf("Please enter the original string:\n");
    GetString(originalstring);

    printf("Please enter the pattern:\n");
    GetString(patternstring);

    printf("Please enter the replacement:\n");
    GetString(replacement);

    StringReplace(originalstring, patternstring, replacement);
    printf("The Resultant string is %s\n", originalstring);
}


void StringReplace(char *original, char *pattern, char *replacement){
    for(int i = 0; *(original + i) != '\0'; i++){
        if(*(pattern) == *(original + i)){
            for(int x = 0; *(pattern + x) == *(original + i + x);  x++){
                if(x == 1){  
                    *(original + i + (x - 1)) = *(replacement + (x - 1));
                    *(original + i + x) = *(replacement + x);
                }
                if(x >= 2){
                    *(original + i + x) = *(replacement + x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
} // this is supposed to replace the pattern string with the replacement string if they have 2 or more similar characters in succession
```

Comment: The nests get confusing. You should use [strstr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) if you're allowed (or roll your own if you're not allowed).. either way, it should be a function call to tell you where `s2` is located in `s1`. After that you don't need any loops. You know where `s2` is located in `s1` and how long it is. That's enough information to build a new string that replaces `s2` in `s1` with `s3`. IMO it will be easier to deal with if you split out the different tasks into functions, rather than mashing it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check some of the conditions.,
If pattern string was found in the original string, then check size_of(s2) with size_of(s3). if s3 >= s2 , then simply remove pattern string from original string and replace it with s3. Else case find the size difference between s3 and s2 and then remove pattern string from original string only with that size difference..Finally replace that place with s3.Hope This might helps:)